# Spring Data Neo4J & CRUD - How requesting an entity A based on an entity B, when A containing a collection of B

Tags: collections, spring-data-neo4j, crud-repository

Basically, I have these entities:

```
@Entity
class A {
   Set<B> SetOfB
}

@Entity
class B {
    ...
}
```

And I need a method in my CRUD Repository allowing getting a List if A contains B in its SetOfB.

When I am using:

```
A findBySetOfBContains(B b)
```

I got:

```
The attribute 'setOfB' is not mapped to a Graph property!
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workarround by searching for B before and using the uuid of B:

`findBySetOfB_Uuid(String uuid)`

That works well.